# Trouble downgrading/upgrading subscription on Stripe with PHP

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe for my recurring payment for my SAAS.

The problem I'm facing today is : I would like to offer to my client the choice to upgrade or downgrade their subscription to my service.

So the code I have actually is the following (according to the doc [here](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading)):

```
\Stripe\Subscription::update($subscriptionID, [
    'items' => [
        'id' => $itemID,
        'plan' => $planId
    ]
]);
```

The `$subscriptionID`, `$itemID` and `$planId` return my the right value I need but no update on the Stripe side.

I have just this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Invalid array",
    "param": "items"
  }
}
```

Any help on his please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Documention says that you have to send a key `'proration_date'` and `plan` seems to be a string, not int, but I'm not sure what you are sending, though.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cover items in one more array level, like so:

```php
\Stripe\Subscription::update($subscriptionID, [
    'items' => [
        [
          'id' => $itemID,
          'plan' => $planId
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was working using this code:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($CustomerId);
$subscription = $customer->subscriptions->retrieve($subscriptionID);
$customer->updateSubscription(['plan' => $planId]);
$customer->save();
```

Strange that the Stripe API do not talk about this solution.

Comment: subscriptions->retrieve does not have items parameter, so it not the same